# setShared Causes Text to Layer and Look Terrible

Tags: docusignapi

We can have 4-5 people signing contracts at once, and are currently using the 'setShared' function to share text across all signing experiences for each client.  However, when we use this, the text on the final contract comes out very blurry because the text layers get stacked on top of each other.

Sample text here:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your Envelope Creation code? I am specifically looking for how you are creating the tabs.

Comment: Can I mail it to you?  I'd rather not put it on SO.  I can also mail you a sample API call.  Feel free to mail me: chris@dzoba.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think setting Shared property is causing the problem.  If you are setting the **bold** property on the tab then I suggest removing it. Also trying changing the font/fontSize properties to get the result you are expecting.

Comment: This is correct.  While setting bold for a bit of text works fine for individual clients, bold text that has been shared looks bad on the final, combined document.  Removing the bold property fixes things on the final combined PDF. Thank you!